# How to round any decimal number less than one to show only one number at the end in R?

Tags: r

How to round any decimal number less than one to show only one number at the end?.

```
0.00045454 -> 0.0005

0.024 -> 0.02

0.2 - > 0.2

0.000000007020 - > 0.000000007

0.000000008 - > 0.000000008
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `log10` with `ceiling`.

```
fRoundEnd <- function(x) round(x, ceiling(-log10(x)))
fRoundEnd(0.00045454)
#> [1] 5e-04
fRoundEnd(0.024)
#> [1] 0.02
fRoundEnd(0.2)
#> [1] 0.2
fRoundEnd(0.000000007020)
#> [1] 7e-09
fRoundEnd(0.000000008)
#> [1] 8e-09
fRoundEnd(2022)
#> [1] 2000
fRoundEnd(c(0.00045454, 0.024, 0.2, 0.000000007020, 0.000000008, 2022))
#> [1] 5e-04 2e-02 2e-01 7e-09 8e-09 2e+03
```

Comment: would you know how to make sure that the numbers are rounded up?. I would like 'fRoundEnd(0.045)` to be `0.05`

Comment: One way: `round(x + 10^ceiling(log10(x))/20, ceiling(-log10(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `signif`

```
signif(c(0.00045454, 0.024, 0.2, 0.000000007020, 0.000000008, 2022), 1)
# [1] 5e-04 2e-02 2e-01 7e-09 8e-09 2e+03
```

Comment: Hi, @dww, would you know why `signif(0.085, 1)` is `0.08` but `signif(0.0856, 1)` is `0.09`. I would like the numbers to be rounded up (`signif(0.085, 1`) to be `0.09`

Comment: r uses the common convention of "round half even".  "A tie-breaking rule without positive/negative bias and without bias toward/away from zero is round half to even". This is generally better than always rounding up, which introduces bias.  E.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even